# ToolTip fadeout when in focus

Tags: jquery

I have a simple code where I show the tooltip (by changing the display property) when you hover over a element. is there a way where tooltip does not fadeout when I hover over tooltip.

```
$('.element').mouseenter(function(){  
    $(this).find('.tooltip').fadeIn();
}).mouseleave(function(){       
    $(this).find('.tooltip').fadeOut();  // I want the tooltip to not fadeout if move is over tooltip element
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(this).find('.tooltip').mouseover(function(){  
$(this).find('.tooltip').stop().fadeTo('fast', 1);
});
$(this).find('.tooltip').mouseout(function() {
$(this).find('.tooltip').stop().fadeTo('fast', 0);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Description

If your tooltip is a child element of your `.element` it will not disapear.

Another thing, i suggest you use jQuery's `.hover()` method for that.

Check out my sample and this [jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/bmgh8/1/)

#### Sample

```
<div class="element"> 
    hover me
    <div style="display:none" class="tooltip">Iam your tooltip</div>
</div>


$('.element').hover(function(){  
     $(this).find('.tooltip').fadeIn();
}, function(){         
     $(this).find('.tooltip').fadeOut();
});
```

#### More Information

- [jQuery.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

Comment: Won't it trigger the `hover` event 2 times if `.tooltip` is hovered if it belongs to the element ?

Comment: @Glide I think that too ;) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would say

```
$('.tooltip,.element').mouseenter(function() {  
  $(this).find('.tooltip').fadeIn();
}).mouseleave(function() {       
  $(this).find('.tooltip').fadeOut();
});
```

If there is a space between the tooltip and the element then you will need a delay before the hide, in that case I'd suggest you to use a plugin like the excellent [qtip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/docs/hide/) for example.